# How can I reduce the power dissipated across this MOSFET without affecting avalanche?

Tags: heatsink, fet, back-emf

previous and very relevant question [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/552279/would-a-mosfet-driver-be-a-suitable-replacement-for-this-circuitry-and-would-it). I want to reduce or remove entirely the heatsink that is attached to my switching MOSFET. It heats up due to the back-EMF generated by the large inductor that it switches on/off. I can't use a freewheeling diode as I need the current drop-off and subsequent avalanche to happen as quickly as possible. This is the circuit and the expected voltage and current generated:
[image]

[image]

Zooming in on this you can see that switching voltage is 12V:
[image]

As you can see, vn006 is the voltage across the inductor that stays at 12V for a period of 50us and then switches off. This causes a large back-EMF of a few hundred volts. I(L1)is the current within the coil, it slowly increases as the FET is on and then sharply drops when the FET is off. The circuit in this configuration works perfectly but the issue is that the FET requires a large heatsink.

In the answer to the linked previous question it was suggested to make an LC series resonant circuit, where at the end of the resonance half-period, voltage on the capacitor is back to zero and current in the inductor has reversed direction. The FET's body diode turns on, and the energy stored in the inductor returns back to the power supply. But adding a capacitor between the inductor and ground just causes oscillations and completely removes the back-EMF. What am I doing wrong here?:
[image]

[image]

Adding a small value resistor in parallel with the cap will remove a lot of these issues, but then isn't that making the addition of the cap redundant? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated. In addition I would like to keep the high-side switch if possible.

Comment: You know you can set white as a background colour. You get much improved contrast levels. [Discussion](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7406/schematic-diagram-background-colour-preferences).

Comment: I've spent the past 5 minutes trying to figure it out

Comment: *Launch LTspice XVII and click “Tools” -> “Color Preferences” in the menu bar to bring up the Color Palette Editor. You can select the WaveForm, Schematic, or Netlist displayed on the tab, enter the RGB values, or move the slide bar to change each color.* - not hard to find this out and I never use LTSpice!

Comment: I changed the background to white, but to me it looks terrible. I'm going to keep the background black for the purposes of this question.

Comment: The energy in your inductor must go somewhere.  By removing the flyback diode you are ensuring that the energy will have to be dissipated by your MOSFET.  I think you'll find that either way, the speed is going to be the same but the MOSFET is going to take the abuse of the voltage spike if you leave the diode out.

Comment: I actually cannot see this: *As you can see, purple is the voltage across the inductor that stays at 12V for a period of 50us* (even though the background is black).

Comment: @Andy aka are you suggesting that it may be a false statement or that you cannot physically see the image due to the colours?

Comment: The transistor has a built-in body diode, how do you plan on not using it? BTW, that means `D1` is useless there, unless you disabled the body diode in the transistor's `.model`. Not lastly, not having a parallel resistor across the LC means the Q will be very high and you won't be able to tame the decaying oscillations. The cap's purpose is to smooth the switching, not to provide high-Q oscillations. Think resonant SMPS.

Comment: I cannot see anywhere that corresponds with 12 volts for 50 us on the purple trace.

Comment: Also, if you want to talk about a representation of a (mildly) accurate circuit, you can't use the generic BJTs, or the ideal diode. (is the red line supposed to mask the `.model` for the MOSFET? if yes, why?)

Comment: I've edited the question for clarity. This a small part of a much larger circuit and the .model wasn't relevant. I've isolated the specific circuit and cleaned it up.

Answer (score 1):

OK -- Lots of details left out, and I'm assuming that if you can put a cap in series with the coil, you can drive it from the low side.

If you've got enough power being dissipated that your TO-220 FET requires a "comically large heat sink" then no matter what you do to *dissipate* the heat, that component will get hot.  If you want to reduce the heat (and lower your power consumption, to boot) then you need to recapture the energy and use it.

M1 and L1 you have.  When you turn off M1, D1 conducts and dumps energy into C1.  Size C1 to get the voltage you want.

The key here is that if you just put a resistor in parallel with C1, it'll get hot instead of the FET -- if that's OK, do it and be happy.  Just size it so that C1 is mostly discharged at the end of a cycle.  If it *is" a problem, then design a circuit that'll take the energy you're dumping into C1 and feeds it back into your +12V line.  This'll require a switching supply, probably a lot like an off-line switcher, and it's probably not worth it unless you really need to keep the heat out, or you have more than a couple of watts of power to recover.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj1z2K.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: The circuit works fine in its present configuration but it consists of aT0-220 FET with a comically large heatsink compared to the surrounding SMD circuitry. This circuit is for a metal detector and it needs the back-EMF for determining the presence of metal. I was hoping that there would be a nice way of getting rid of the the heat. Maybe dissipating it across the coil rather than the FET. Moving the heating issue from the FET to a resistor would just increase component count rather than solve the problem but I get your point.

Comment: Text edited (soon).